Why my double pendulum loses energy? Written in C++
I tried to write a physicaly accurate double pendulum. And I found a method called XPBD.
https://matthias-research.github.io/pages/publications/XPBD.pdf
you can read it from here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzuNFaqsfEY
As you can see in the video, the system is losing energy over time. I think this is due to the length constraint in the Spring class, but I couldn't find my mistake. How can I make the system work properly without losing energy?
void Spring::solveForConstraints(float dt) {

    Vector2Custom diffVector = end_p->pos - start_p->pos;
    double currentLen = diffVector.Length();

    double a_hat = inverseStiffnes / (dt * dt);
    double w1 = start_p->invMass;
    double w2 = end_p->invMass;


    if (currentLen != originalLen) {


        double lambda = 0;
        double lambda_delta;

        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
        {

            double C = (end_p->pos - start_p->pos).Length() - originalLen;

            Vector2Custom delta_C1 = (start_p->pos - end_p->pos).Normalize();
            Vector2Custom delta_C2 = (end_p->pos - start_p->pos).Normalize(); // -delta_C1

            // formula from paper   delta_x = inverseMass * delta_C * delta_lambda;
            // formula from paper   delta lambda = (-C - â * lambda) / (delta_C * inverseMass  + a_hat);



            if ((!start_p->isFixed) && (!end_p->isFixed)) { // w1 / (w1+ w2) * (l-l0 ) * diffvectorNormalized


                lambda_delta = (-C - a_hat * lambda) / (delta_C1.DotProduct(delta_C1 * w1) + delta_C2.DotProduct(delta_C2 * w2) + a_hat);
                lambda += lambda_delta;

                Vector2Custom delta_x1 = delta_C1 * lambda_delta * w1;
                Vector2Custom delta_x2 = delta_C2 * lambda_delta * w2;

                start_p->pos = start_p->pos + delta_x1;
                end_p->pos = end_p->pos + delta_x2;


            }
            else if (!start_p->isFixed) {

                lambda_delta = (-C - a_hat * lambda) / (delta_C1.DotProduct(delta_C1 * w1) + a_hat);
                lambda += lambda_delta;

                Vector2Custom delta_x1 = delta_C1 * lambda_delta * w1;

                start_p->pos = start_p->pos + delta_x1;

            }
            else if (!end_p->isFixed) {

                lambda_delta = (-C - a_hat * lambda) / (delta_C2.DotProduct(delta_C2 * w2) + a_hat);
                lambda += lambda_delta;

                Vector2Custom delta_x2 = delta_C2 * lambda_delta * w2;

                end_p->pos = end_p->pos + delta_x2;

            }
        }
    }
}

the part where I got the formulas 
formulas 17 and 18 is what i tried to do.
for better understanding. there is a algorithm below
algorithm
Below is where i call the function.

        // Update 
        int substeps = 10;
        float dt_sub = dt / substeps;

        for (int j = 0; j < substeps; j++)
        {

            //Verlet Integration
            // First, guess where is particles is going to be.

            for (int i = 1; i < numOfParticles; i++)
            {
                Particle* currentBall = &ParticleList[i];

                Vector2Custom accVector = gravVec * currentBall->invMass;               //acceleration vector  a = F/m 
                currentBall->pos = currentBall->pos + accVector * (dt_sub * dt_sub);    //add acc * dt * dt 
                currentBall->pos = currentBall->pos + currentBall->speed * dt_sub;      //add speed * dt

            }

            // Solve lenght Constraints
      
            for (int j = 0; j < springList.size(); j++)
            {
                springList[j].solveForConstraints(dt_sub);
            }

            //Update velocity
            for (int i = 1; i < numOfParticles; i++)
            {
                Particle* currentBall = &ParticleList[i];
                currentBall->speed = (currentBall->pos - currentBall->old_pos) / dt_sub;
                currentBall->old_pos = currentBall->pos;

            }

        }



How can I fix the formula if I am using it incorrectly?

I'd imagine its just rounding errors, doing incremental calculations like this tend to amplify floating point errors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_error_mitigation

@AlanBirtles but in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gQQAO4I1Ck&t=314s pezza uses same xpbd method. His pendulum works fine.

Have you tried running their code and measuring the energy in the same way you do?

I tried to run but couldn't get it to work. The repo is complicated for me. But I'll try to run it again now.

First, replace all float by double. The float type is often not precise enough for scientific computations.

I replaced floats to double but looks like nothing changed.

@AlanBirtles The repo is very complicated and there is no explanation. I was able to build it but it doesn't work .  Do you have any other suggestions?

What has a spring got to do with a double pendulum?

@lastchance it is just a class name for the length constraint. You can set the stiffness of the constraint. If inverseStiffnes is zero, it behaves like a solid stick .

I should just use the Euler-Lagrange equations for two degrees of freedom; (the two angles made by the pendulum rods with the vertical, for example). Then you will be guaranteed to conserve energy. Whatever your method is, you would do better to include the actual equations that you are using in your post (not to be ferreted out of somebody's research report) and present complete code that can actually be used to run it.

@lastchance When I use the Euler-Lagrange equations, will I be able to move the point it is hanging on? I want a system that responds to the movement of the point?

Yes, you can move the point (horizontal momentum will be conserved, as well as energy) but could you please provide a clear statement of your problem within your question.

It actually states that energy loss will be a limitation of the XPBD method in the paper:

5 Damping


Our method is derived from an implicit time stepping scheme that
naturally includes some dissipation of mechanical energy. Nevertheless, it can be useful to model additional constraint damping[.......]

Energy loss is expected.

You may be right, but the energy loss was very high, that's why I asked the question. I set the substep number to 10, when I increased the number to 6000, the performance decreased but the accuracy rate increased a lot. I think that was the problem.
